# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread encountered

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, java.util.concurrent

I'm using a thread pool to do some work. My pool size is just 8.
But I got the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at com.TransferFiles.transferFilesToHadoop(TransferFiles.java:88)
    at com.TransferJob.execute(TransferJob.java:25)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:555)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:986)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy1.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at $Proxy1.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:676)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1095)
    at com.FileCopyRoutine.call(TransferFiles.java:325)
    at com.FileCopyRoutine.call(TransferFiles.java:257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I'm using:

```
private static final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(TransferToHadoopUtilities.numOfThreads);
```

numOfThreads=8

```
Future<Boolean> futureTask =  exec.submit(new FileCopyRoutine(srcSubResultPath, destSubResultPath,execId));
```

FileCopyRoutine implements Callable. I might do hundreds of submit at the same time.
Could anyone please give me some hint about this error?

Comment: I added the 'hadoop' tag as it seems to be relevant in this context.

Comment: Well, apparently jvm has run out of free memory. Have you allocated any additional memory or are you launching your application with default memory settings?

Comment: How many jobs are you submitting to the pool?  Is it really 100s or more?

Comment: Thank you for replying.So far, it cannot exceed submitting more than 100 I think.

Comment: Then you should write up a good answer and accept your own answer.  Or you might consider editing the question or the subject to provide more details so people can add better answers.

Comment: What is the size of each job?  What are you setting your java heap space to (are you setting the '-Xmx' flag to anything at the command line)?  The default heap space size is 128Mb, I believe, and each thread in Java gets 4Mb of stack space allocated to it, but if you forgot the 'm' in '-Xmx[some number]m' at the command line, then the number is interpreted as bytes.  Just some ideas.

Comment: Cannot create native thread is generally caused by the heap being too large, not too small.

Comment: It is very likely not the thread-stack size.  Though I usually set that at -Xss128k (128k is sufficient for even large enterprisey servers).  It is very likely the main heap.  Try -Xmx1024m or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to create a thread indicates native memory - not heap.   If you are on a 32-bit system, having -Xmx set TOO high can actually starve native memory

Comment: Thread stacks are created in native memory - they are not part of the heap.  Now there is a very small TLH (thread local heap) associated with each thread that is on the heap - - but that is not what is happening here.  

It would also help to know what OS this is, if it is 32-bit/64-bit, what JDK is being used, what the max heapsize is set to, etcetcetc